# Vuetfiy Tabs Not Displayed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried to implement tabs to my component. Tabs can't be displayed. I took the same example from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs `TypeError: this.$parent.addTab is not a function` error is logged on console. I upgraded the vuetify version but it isn't working. What could be the problem? Component content is below.

```
<template><div>
    <v-tabs v-model="active"
            color="cyan"
            dark
            slider-color="yellow">
        <v-tab v-for="n in 3"
               :key="n"
               ripple>
            Item {{ n }}

        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="n in 3"
                    :key="n">
            <v-card flat>
                <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>

    <div class="text-xs-center mt-3">
        <v-btn @click="next">next tab</v-btn>
    </div>
</div></template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            active: null,
            text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        next() {
            const active = parseInt(this.active)
            this.active = (active < 2 ? active + 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}</script>
```

My app.vue:

```
<v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer persistent clipped enable-resize-watcher v-model="drawer" app>
        <MenuComponent></MenuComponent>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar color="cyan darken-3" dark fixed clipped-left app>
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>...</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-btn @click="logout" icon>
            <v-icon>exit_to_app</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
    <main>
        <v-content>
            <vue-snotify></vue-snotify>
            <v-container fluid>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </main>
    <v-footer color="cyan darken-3" app fixed>
        <span class="white--text"> &copy; 2018 </span>
    </v-footer>
</v-app>
```

Comment: This works fine for me: [gif of proof](https://i.imgur.com/QbZi5Wr.gif). Can you also post up your main html where your `router-view` is?

Comment: @SnakeyHips I added my app.vue

Comment: Mmm what if you were to remove <vue-snotify>? Just a random guess but worth trying in case it's not compatible with tabs.

Comment: No I don't think it is related. But I tried and still not working.

Comment: Perhaps it's an interference from another js library?

Comment: Do you use A La Carte component ? Wich version of Vuetify are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had imported `vue-nav-tabs`. I removed it and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a moment to realise that you don't need href e.g

```
 <v-tabs
  v-model="tabs"
  background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
  centered
  dark
  icons-and-text
>
  <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>


  <v-tab href="#tab-2">
    Favorites
    <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
  </v-tab>

  <v-tab href="#tab-3">
    Nearby
    <v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>

<v-tabs-items v-model="tabs">
  <v-tab-item
   
  >
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text><p>hey</p></v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
        <v-tab-item
   
  >
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text> <p>hey</p></v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

Removing href="#tab-2" and href="#tab-3" worked because I have not set the value if you don't necessarily need to set the value in v-tab-item.

```
 <v-tab-item
        v-for="i in 3"
        :key="i"
        :value="'tab-' + i"
      >
```